# Using an if statement for detecting whether value is returning undefined not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, undefined

I'm making an app using React-Use-Cart. I am using the getItem hook to detect changes in the price. Its really simple, and this is how this works: if the item has a quantity more than 0, then it will return the price or if it's 0, then it will return undefined.

So, here is my program -

```
const totalitem = getItem(products.id).itemTotal;
const totalitem2 = JSON.stringify(totalitem);
```

and

```
<h1>{totalitem === "undefined" ? "Zero!" : totalitem2}</h1>
```

This is not working! When totalitem gets to 0, which is undefined, the React DOM throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'itemTotal')

I really don't know how to solve this issue, and I'm pretty sure that this is a common one. Can anyone please help me out? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The problem is not that `totalitem` is `undefined` (or `"undefined"`), but rather that `getItem(products.id)` returns `undefined`. Store it in a `const item` and test *that*, before accessing `item.itemTotal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem (which is triggering the error) is due to accessing `itemTotal` property on `undefined`. You can use optional chaining to solve this.

```
const totalitem = getItem(products.id)?.itemTotal;
const totalitem2 = JSON.stringify(totalitem);
```

The second problem is checking `"undefined"` as a string. It should be without quotes.

```
<h1>{totalitem === undefined ? "Zero!" : totalitem2}</h1>
```